# Button Column in a datagrid

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a grid and the first column is a button for each line,with Excluir ("Delete").

[image]

When i click in the button i need to recover the button action and which row it was clicked,i'm trying this but don't work.

```
Private Sub dgAdm_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

     IF e.ColumnIndex = dgAdm.Columns["Delete"].Index AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0

            Console.WriteLine("Button on row {0} clicked", e.RowIndex)
     End
```

Someone knows what i'm missing

Comment: `but don't work` is a horrible problem description.  `&&` ??? did you mean `AndAlso`?

Comment: It says DataGridViewCellEventArgs is not defined. And in the "delete" says it expects a identifier

Comment: Please post the full code, that's not a valid vb. net syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the **sender** parameter, because it is an `Object` type you must cast it to DataGridview first. here is an example in vb.net how to extract the row and column number via `CellClick` event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim rowNum As Integer = CType(sender, DataGridView).CurrentCell.RowIndex ' get row number
    Dim colNum As Integer = CType(sender, DataGridView).CurrentCell.ColumnIndex ' get col number

    If colNum = 1 Then ' the index of the "delete" button column
        MsgBox("the row number that was clicked: " & rowNum)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: In cases when you sure about actual type of variable use `DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)` it is cheaper and faster.

Comment: thank you! i will adopt that. is it equivalent to `(DatagridView)Sender` in c#?